# Let $A$ be a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound, and let $a \in A$. Then $A$ has a maximal element $u$ such that $u \ge a$.

Tags: order-theory

Let $A$ be a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound, and let $a \in A$. Then $A$ has a maximal element $u$ such that $u \ge a$.

I'm trying to solve this by way of contradiction. If we contradict the hypothesis then for every $u \ge a$, there will be a $x \ge u$. My idea is that we can form a chain by adding $z$ such that $z \ge x$, then we will get a chain that has no upper bound. However, I am not sure how to formulate such a chain. How can I make this proof rigorous?

Comment: This is a very close relative of Zorn's Lemma. Has Zorn's Lemma been done in your course?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $B=\{\,x\in A:x\ge a\,\}$ and try proving $B$ (with the induced order) satisfies the same property (every chain has an upper bound); by Zorn's lemma, $B$ has a maximal element; is this also maximal in $A$?

Comment: I proved it using my hint can you check if it's correct? Firsts, B satisfying the property is obvious since B is a subset of A with the same order, thus a chain in B must be a chain in A. And so by Zorn's lemma, if we let b be the maximal element of B. Now suppose y is a maximal element in A satisfying $\ge a$, then since $y \in B$, and y is maximal, $y \ge b$, then by definition of maximal element, $b=y$. Is this complete?

Comment: @user135204 Not really: you have to prove that $b$ is maximal in $A$. If $x\in A$ and $b\le x$, then $a\le x$, so $x\in B$ and, by maximality of $b$, $x=b$.

Comment: Oh I get it I can't just assume that there's such maximal element in A I need to prove that b is such an element. Thanks for clearing it up!!